# Mapping Docker Volumes in a Cluster/Docker-Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am running Docker Swarm with 3-Masters and 3-Worker nodes.
On this Swarm, I have an Elastic search container which reads data from multiple log files and then writes the data into a directory. Later it reads data from this directory and shows me the logs on a UI.

Now the problem is that I am running only 1 instance of this Elastic Search Container and say for some reason it goes down then docker swarm start this on another machine. Since I have 6 machines I have created the particular directory on all the machines, but whenever I start the docker stack the ES container starts and starts reading/writing directory on the machine where it is running.

Is there a way that we can

- Force docker swarm to run a container on a particular machine

or

- Map volume to shared/network drive

Answer (score 4):

Both are available.

> Force docker swarm to run a container on a particular machine

Add `--constraint` flag when executing `docker service create`. Some [introduction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#specify-service-constraints---constraint).

> Map volume to shared/network drive

Use docker volume with a driver that supports writing files to an external storage system like NFS or Amazon S3. More [introduction](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#share-data-among-machines).

Comment: Thanks For the useful Info !!